# im using github pages with jekyll using liquid syntax. there is weird thing

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

before fixing code,

[image]

then rendered like this,

[image]

---

because i want delete side bar that explain me. so i fixed code,

[image]

then rendered like what i want

[image]

---

but i want to leave old code. so i used comment block like this

[image]

then rendered like this

[image]

why rendered "-->"? and why rendered right weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by using liquid comment block

```
{% comment %} {% endcomment %}
```